# How to get shipping address by invoice number?

Tags: magento-1.9, invoice, sales, shipping-address

When i print multiple invoices, i add new PDF page and on that page i print Invoice number, order number, and Total amount. [image]
And to do this i did code 
`foreach ($invoices as $invoice) {

```
        array_push($this::$invs,$invoice);
    }
    $grandtotal = 0;
    for($i=0;$i<sizeof($this::$invs);$i++){

        $order = $this::$invs[$i]->getOrder();
        $amount = $order->getGrandTotal();
        $grandtotal = $grandtotal + $amount;
        $page->setFillColor(new Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0));

        $page->drawText('Inc#: '.$this::$invs[$i]->getIncrementId().'        Ordr#: '.$this::$invs[$i]->getOrderId().'      Total Amount: '.$amount, 20, $this::$p, 'UTF-8');
        $this::$p=$this::$p-15;
    }`
```

in `app/code/local/Mage/sales/Model/order/pdf/invoice.php` and it's working fine.
Now i want to add shipping address of every order with it. As you see that i got invoice Id's not Order Id's. If any one can help please.

Comment: Do you have your order id?

Comment: No, i don not have it. And that thing is making problem. @mujas

Comment: what do you expect to do?

Comment: See the edit please. @mujas

Comment: you have your order increment id, you can follow fabian's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Magento models, you have to take multiple steps:

1. load the invoice by number `$number`

   ```
   $invoice = Mage::getModel('sales/order_invoice')->loadByIncrementId($number);
   ```
2. load order from invoice

   ```
   $order = $invoice->getOrder();
   ```
3. load shipping address from order

   ```
   $shipping = $order->getShippingAddress();
   ```
4. finally, get the street

   ```
   $shipping->getStreet();
   ```

---

**Update:** I see you updated your question with code. You already loaded the order `$order`, so you can start with step (3).

Comment: I follow your method from step (3). When i draw this on PDF  `$page->drawText('Address: '.$shipping->getStreet(), 20, $this::$p-200, 'UTF-8');`. On PDF it shows **"Address: Array"**

Comment: Oh, the street is returned as array of lines (usually one element, but you can have one or more "additional address" fields). To display it in one line, use `implode(' ', $shipping->getStreet())`, or to display it in multiple lines in the pdf, `foreach` over `$shipping->getStreet()` and call `$page->drawText()` for each line.

Answer (score 0):

Load Invoice using your Invoice Number:

```
$invoice = Mage::getModel('sales/order_invoice')->load($id); 
$order = $invoice->getOrder();  //Get order details
```

Then

```
$address = $order->getShippingAddress();    
$custName = $address->getName();
$custAddr = $address->getStreetFull();
$region = $address->getRegion();
$country = $address->getCountry();
```

Comment: I am in the situation that i don't have **Order ID** . I have to get address by **Invoice number**. Please tell me if you got a solution for this.

Comment: I updated my answer. Check it , If this helps you.